# How to save strings in individual lines in a text file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm preparing an automation script which can check spelling mistakes from a website and show me the misspelled words and prepare a list for the same. To do this, I need to split sentences to the individual words so that my script can check spellings.

I'm opening URL's sequentially from a CSV file and copy-pasting all the content of each URL to a separate text file. Then I read that newly created text file and try to separate all the words into individual strings. Once I have the file with one word on each line, it will be fed to my spell check script.

For example, suppose a website has the content "Hello World". My code will create a new text file named `1.txt` which will contain the text "Hello World". From that I'm trying to read the text file and create a new file named `1_word_by_word.txt` which contains "Hello" in the 1st line and "World" in the 2nd.

Somehow I'm printing only the last word of the sentence. But when I send it to the console it's printing properly.

My code is:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    System.out.println(scan.next());
    String word_by_word = scan.next();
    String TestFile_2 = "Word_By_Word.txt";
    File FC_2 = new File(TestFile_2);
    FC_2.createNewFile();

    //Create Object of java FileWriter and BufferedWriter class.
    //Writing In to file.
    FileWriter FileWriter_2 = new FileWriter(TestFile_2);
    FileWriter_2.write(word_by_word);
    FileWriter_2.flush();
    FileWriter_2.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA Stack Exchange. Could you please edit your post to explain how it relates to testing? As it stands, the question reads as a straightforward programming question.

Comment: Hello Kate, I'm preparing an automation script which can check spelling mistakes from a website and show me the misspelled words and prepare a list for the same, and for this, I require to split sentences to the individual words so that my script can check spellings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify your code to something like this:

```
File FC_2 = new File(TestFile_2);
FC_2.createNewFile();
FileWriter FileWriter_2 = new FileWriter(TestFile_2);
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String word_by_word = scan.next();
    System.out.println(word_by_word);
    FileWriter_2.write(word_by_word+"\n");

}
FileWriter_2.flush();
FileWriter_2.close();
```

You are iterating line-by-line and writing words one at a time into the file. In the while loop of your code, a new instance of File and FileWriter is being created for every line. This is not needed. What is happening in your case is that the older file is getting overwritten every time a new line is encountered.

Also, the print statement that you have contains a scan.next() as a result of which word_by_word is reading only the next word (and missing the first word of that line).

In addition, if you want every word captured to be entered into a new line of the output file, then add a "\n" to your FileWriter part of the code. Note that the last line will just have a newline character.

Hope this helps! :)

Although, I do agree with Kate here. This question does not have anything to do with testing/automation.

Comment: Thanks, @Tushar for your answer. I'll try this solution and let you know soon. And as I already said in my comments section that this thing is required in my testing (explained my whole testing scenario), so just don't try to ruin my question here.

Comment: You are welcome, @Dhairya. And my intent isn't to "ruin" your question in any way. As has been said, this particular forum is for questions pertaining to Software Testing and/or Automation. Even though your problem statement is that of a test scenario using selenium, the question you posted does not have anything to do with it. This is a general question around File read/write in Java. Hence the suggestion to use the general forum.